# Capitalization with parentheses at the beginning of a slide bullet point

Tags: capitalization, parentheses

Which is correct for a bullet point in a slide presentation?

> - (Continuous) Application deployment

or

> - (Continuous) application deployment

This is *not* a title, but just a fragment like you’d see in a bullet point.

Comment: I hope someone can think of a clearly better one but, in the meantime, let me say I think the latter preferable, even if there is no rules for it.

Comment: I also don't know of a rule and I also think the second one looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awkwardness arises not from the capitalization, but from the parentheses themselves. What do you intend to convey by them?

- **Application deployment, where the continuous nature is implicit:** Then just write either *Continuous application deployment* or *Application deployment*, and get rid of the confusing clutter.
- **Both continuous and traditional application deployment** in the same bullet point: Then write either *Application deployment* or *Application deployment (continuous and traditional)* or make two separate bullet points.

Answer (score 2):

The capitalization is awkward only because of the misplacement of the qualifier "continuous" in front.  Bulleted lists should indicate hierarchy by indentation, and also by keeping the most important word at left. If, as I suspect, this bullet is followed later by another contrasting or complementary bullet item—about, perhaps,  "staged" or "intermittent" deployment, I would use

- Application Deployment (continuous)

then that other bullet would say

- Application Deployment ( {the other kind} ).

Or lower-case the word "deployment" if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Bullet points can usually afford to bend grammar rules, since they are typically fragments rather than sentences.

If there was just one bullet point, and the meaning was "application deployment, possibly continuous" then I would write it with all initial caps, i.e.

- (Continuous) Application Deployment

This is essentially treating the bullet point like a title (which is arguably OK) and also minimising the issue with the capitalization of the first non-parenthesised word.